# No Java folder located in Library despite JDK installation

Tags: java, encryption, java-8, jce

Currently running OSX El Capitan on a recently set up computer. I'm trying to set up Java's unlimited crypto policy which requires me to modify some files within my current jre, but I can't find the Java folder that is supposed to be located within Library.

I've run `/usr/libexec/java_home` which shows me `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home` however within my Library folder, there is no Java folder, even when I try and navigate through terminal it says Java folder doesn't exist. After trying to reinstall JDK 1.8, still no luck and I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is not the `Library` folder in your home directory, this is the `Library` folder in the root file system on your main disk.

So in Terminal the command

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk
```

should work.

For different releases of Java replace `jdk1.8.0_91.jdk` with the appropriate release.

To list what is in the directory use:

```
ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

Comment: I got `cd: no such file or directory: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk
` Please help me to find Java Home.

Comment: @Harsha You have to replace `jdk1.8.0_91.jdk` with whatever your actual Java release is. Use `ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` to list which jdks are installed

Answer (score 2):

Go to Macintosh HD/Library/Java
not to username/Library

Comment: This was already explained in the first sentence of the accepted answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).